# Bounded sets on $\mathbb R$ proof-verification

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

Question:

Let $A$ be a set of real numbers that is bounded above and set $\alpha = supA$. Let $B=\{-a:a\in A\}$. Prove that $infB=-\alpha$.

My approach: 
(edited with the help of a comment by Dave)

For $-\alpha$ to be equal to $infB$, the following two statements should satisfy.

1. $-\alpha\leq b$ for all $b\in B$.
2. If there exist $\mu$ which is a lower bound for $B$, then $-\alpha\geq\mu$

We first note that $\alpha$ being $supA$ implies that $a\leq \alpha, \forall a \in A$. This can also be stated as $-a \geq -\alpha$.

Now we prove statement 1 by a contradiction. Assume $\exists b \in B: b< -\alpha$. Now set $b=-a$. This results in $-a<-\alpha$. Which is a contradiction (see the previous paragraph). Hence, statement 1 is true.

Now we prove statement 2. Let $\mu$ be a lower bound on $B$. This implies that, $\mu \leq -a, \forall -a$. By rearranging we get $-\mu \geq a, \forall a$. Therefore, $-\mu$ is an upper bound on $A$. But, $\alpha \leq -\mu$ since $\alpha = supA$. We can rearrange again to get $-\alpha \geq \mu$ as required.

We now conclude our proof is complete.

I need to check whether this proof is right. Especially, the proof of the second statement.

Comment: Should be "$-\alpha\geq\mu$" in the statement of condition 2. Your proof of 1 looks good (should say something like "now we can write $b=-a$ for some $a\in A$"), but you could even just do it directly (which you basically do in your note above the proof paragraph). For part 2 we don't know that $-\alpha\in B$ (i.e. we need not have $\alpha\in A$).

Comment: @Dave I corrected statement 2. Exactly! I need a clean way to get around statement 2. Now I see that my approach in proving statement 2 is wrong.

Comment: To phrase it differently, why is $\mu$, where $\mu > -\alpha$, not a least bound of $B$?

Comment: For part 2 you'll need to appeal to the fact that $\alpha$ is the supremum of $A$, not just an upper bound for $A$. I'd suggest starting with a lower bound $\mu$ for $B$ and showing that $-\mu$ would be an upper bound for $A$ and going from there.

Comment: Let $\mu$ be a lower bound on $B$. This implies that, $\mu \leq -a \forall -a$. By rearranging we get $-\mu \geq a \forall a$. Therefore, $-\mu$ is an upper bound on $A$. But, $\alpha \leq -\mu$ since $\alpha = supA$. We can rearrange again to get $-\alpha \geq \mu$ as required.

Comment: Looks good to me!